# Trying to make a route in Angular on dropdown item, not working?

Tags: angular, routes

I have a route `/gallery` and in routing module it has 2 children

```
    path: "gallery",
    component: GalleryComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "photoAlbums",
        component: AlbumsComponent,
        children: [{ path: "photos", component: PhotosComponent }],
      },
      {
        path: "videoAlbums",
        component: VideoAlbumComponent,
        children: [{ path: "videos", component: VideosComponent }],
      },
    ],
  },
```

Now I am trying to connect the routes on dropdown. Once u hover over gallery u can click on it to go to `/galery` or click on 1 of dropdown and go on them `/photoAlbums` or `/videoAlbums`.

This is what I have in my app.component.html:

```
      <a
        routerLink="gallery"
        style="text-decoration: none;"
        class="fontSize dropbtn"
        >Gallery</a
      >
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a
          routerLink="/photoAlbums"
          style="text-decoration: none;"
          class="fontSize dropbtn"
          >Photos</a
        >
        <a
          routerLink="/videoAlbums"
          style="text-decoration: none;"
          class="fontSize dropbtn"
          >Videos</a
        >
      </div>
    </li>
```

Gallery works but photos and videos don't, in console I get this error:
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'videoAlbums'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'videoAlbums' ...

Comment: try with this :  `routerLink: "gallery/photoAlbums"` & `routerLink="gallery/videoAlbums"`

Comment: @micronyks Thanks it worked! Can you tell me, to get just photos, cause currently I am getting both gallery and child component rendered, what to do. I just want to get child once I click on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be,

```
routerLink: "gallery/photoAlbums" & routerLink="gallery/videoAlbums"
```

But in this case, it will render gallery component too.

Because the route  `path: "photoAlbums"` can be accessed through `gallery` route only as `gallery` is the parent of `path: "photoAlbums"`.
It means you can't access phtoAlbums directly until you access gallery component(because child is accessible if parent is loaded).

*Same is applicable to `path="/videoAlbums"`.*

So by default, first you have to load `gallery` path or component.

---

### What can you do ?

1. If these paths don't have parent/child scenario, you can change the routing as follow,

   ```
    { 
        path: "gallery",
        component: GalleryComponent
    },
    {
        path: "photoAlbums",
        component: AlbumsComponent,
        children: [{ path: "photos", component: PhotosComponent }],
    },
    {
        path: "videoAlbums",
        component: VideoAlbumComponent,
        children: [{ path: "videos", component: VideosComponent }],
    },
   ```

all routes are at same level. now `routerLink="/photoAlbums"` && `routerLink="/videoAlbums"` will work.

2. otherwise, you will have to write below piece of code in `gallery.component.html`

   ```
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a
          routerLink="/photoAlbums"
          style="text-decoration: none;"
          class="fontSize dropbtn"
          >Photos</a
        >
        <a
          routerLink="/videoAlbums"
          style="text-decoration: none;"
          class="fontSize dropbtn"
          >Videos</a
        >
   </div>
   ```

after putting it inside gallery's html, `routerLink="/photoAlbums"` && `routerLink="/videoAlbums"` will work.

Answer (score 0):

> routerLink="/photoAlbums"

you need to link the full path -

```
 routerLink="/gallery/photoAlbums"
```